# Linebreak in makeatletter command

Tags: line-breaking

For some reason I get a linebreak when using my `\textlabel` command in the table cell. It seems to work fine for everything else.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[pdftex,bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered,colorlinks=true]{hyperref} % http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\usepackage{nameref}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
    \newcommand*{\textlabel}[2]{%
        \edef\@currentlabel{#1}% Set target label
        \phantomsection% Correct hyper reference link
        #1\label{#2}% Print and store label
    }  
\makeatother

\section{Section}
\paragraph*{\textlabel{Paragraph}{paragraph}}
\paragraph*{}
\begin{tabular}{lp{10cm}}
    \hline
    \textbf{Col 1} & \textbf{Col 2} \\ \hline
    Bla1 & \textlabel{Blubb1}{reference1} \\
    & Description1 \\ 
    Bla2 & \textlabel{Blubb2}{reference2} \\
    & Description2 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Avoid doing things in vertical mode, especially at the start of table cells.

```
\makeatletter
    \newcommand*{\textlabel}[2]{%
        \edef\@currentlabel{#1}% Set target label
        \leavevmode\phantomsection% Correct hyper reference link
         %%%%%%%%%%
        #1\label{#2}% Print and store label
    }  
\makeatother
```

Comment: Excuse me, but could you elaborate a little further? What exactly does 'vertical mode' mean? I have to admit that I haven't written the command by myself, therefore don't really know how it works, however, am very eager to learn.

Comment: _(very simple and somehow incorrect explanation)_ At the beginning of a cell, LaTeX is in "vertical" mode, which means that things "tend to be put atop each other", which makes `\phantomsection` occupy its own line, even though it does not print anything. By `\leavevmode` you "leave vertical mode" and enter "horizontal mode", where things are put next to each other and `\phantomsection` occupies zero horizontal space then.

Comment: I was away from machine but @tohecz gives a good explanation. Searching for "mode" on this site or other tutorials will give other examples of this distinction.